# Is there a free open source API gateway?

Tags: open-source, library, api, slack

I would like a unified library that can interact with many different services' APIs.

In particular, is there such a lib that works for both Okta and Slack?

I know for example that Airbyte works for extracting data from various sources, is there something similar that lets you make API calls?

Comment: Would you mind telling us your motivations for wanting a single gateway? Is it because of networking constraints? Or just because you think one API will be easier to use than several? Okta and Slack have difference purposes, so they won't have many operations in common.

Comment: I would need to integrate more apis than slack and okta. I would also need to integrate other IDMs and also other messaging systems. I would need to integrate with task management tools such as Jira and others like trello and Monday. I would also need to integrate with hr tools like hibob and workday.

Comment: I guess what I want is something that handles the authorization part (oauth) of these apis, it would be nice if it gives me some metrics, then gives me a clean way to interact with these apis through a unified interface.

The setup part of a 3rd party app and handling of the oauth flow is the complex part I am trying to avoid, if a tool can take care of that for me and leave the part of interacting with the apis to me that would also be amazing.

Comment: It seems like you have created two accounts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20two%20accounts,that%20you%20own%20both%20accounts.